# R: all.equal() for multiple objects?

Tags: r

What is the best way to compare more than two objects with `all.equal()`?

Here's one way:

```
foo <- c(1:10)
bar <- letters[1:10]
baz <- c(1:10)

# doesn't work because all.equal() returns a character vector when objects not all equal
  all(sapply(list(bar, baz), all.equal, foo))

# this works
  mode(sapply(list(bar, baz), all.equal, foo)) == "logical" #FALSE

  bar <- c(1:10)

  mode(sapply(list(bar, baz), all.equal, foo)) == "logical" #TRUE
```

**UPDATE:** @BrodieG pointed out that the one-liner above only tells you whether the objects are all equal or not, whereas `all.equal()` tells you what isn't equal about them if they aren't equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this comes as close to the behavior of `all.equal()` as possible.

It returns `TRUE` if the objects are all equal and a list of pairwise comparisons otherwise. It returns a single-item list if only two objects are compared for consistency of output.

```
# function: all.equal.mult()
# description: compares >=2 objects with all.equal()
# input: >=2 comma-separated object names
# output: TRUE or list of pairwise all.equal() object comparisons
# examples:
#   foo <- c(1:10)
#   bar <- c(1:10)
#   foz <- c(1:10)
#   baz <- letters[1:10]
# 
#   all.equal.mult(foo, bar) # TRUE
#   all.equal.mult(foo, baz) # results of all.equal(foo, baz) as one-item list
#   all.equal.mult(foo, bar, foz) # TRUE
#   all.equal.mult(foo, bar, baz) # list of pairwise all.equal() comparisons among objects
all.equal.mult <- function(...) {
  # more than one object required
  if (length(list(...)) < 2) stop("More than one object required")

  # character vector of object names
  names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]

  # matrix of object name pairs
  pairs <- t(combn(names, 2))  

  # if only two objects, return one item list containing all.equal() for them
  if (nrow(pairs) == 1) return(list(all.equal(get(pairs[1,1]), get(pairs[1,2]))))

  # function: eq.fun()
  # description: applies all.equal() to two quoted names of objects
  # input: two quoted names of objects
  # output: list containing all.equal() comparison and "[obj1] vs. [obj2]"
  # examples:
  #   x <- 1
  #   y <- 1
  #   z <- 2
  #   eq.fun("x", "y") # list(TRUE, "x vs. y")
  #   eq.fun("x", "z") # list("Mean relative difference: 1", "x vs. z")
  eq.fun <- function(x, y) {
    all.eq <- all.equal(get(x, inherits=TRUE), get(y, inherits=TRUE))
    name <- paste0(x, " vs. ", y)
    return(list(all.eq, name))
    }

  # list of eq.fun object comparisons
  out <- vector(mode="list", length=nrow(pairs))

  for (x in 1:nrow(pairs)) {
    eq.list <- eq.fun(pairs[x, 1], pairs[x, 2])
    out[[x]] <- eq.list[[1]]
    names(out)[x] <- eq.list[[2]]
    }

  # return TRUE if all objects equal, comparison list otherwise
  if (mode(unlist(out)) == "logical") {return(TRUE)} else {return(out)}
  }
```

Testing 1, 2:

```
foo <- c(1:10)
bar <- c(1:10)
foz <- c(1:10)
baz <- letters[1:10]

all.equal.mult(foo) # Error
all.equal.mult(foo, bar) # TRUE
all.equal.mult(foo, baz) # results of all.equal(foo, baz) as one-item list
all.equal.mult(foo, bar, foz) # TRUE
all.equal.mult(foo, bar, baz) # list of pairwise all.equal() comparisons among objects
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is an option:

```
objs <- mget(c("foo", "bar", "faz"))
outer(objs, objs, Vectorize(all.equal))
```

It's better than yours because it will detect when `bar` and `faz` are the same, even when `foo` isn't.  That said, it does a lot of unnecessary comparisons and will be slow.  For example, if we change `foo` to be `letters[1:10]` we get:

```
    foo         bar         faz        
foo TRUE        Character,2 Character,2
bar Character,2 TRUE        TRUE       
faz Character,2 TRUE        TRUE
```

For details on what went wrong, just subset:

```
outer(objs, objs, Vectorize(all.equal))[1, 2]
```

Produces:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Modes: character, numeric"              
[2] "target is character, current is numeric"
```

If all you care about is that all the objects must be `all.equal`, then your solution is pretty good.

Also, as per comments to limit some of the duplicate calculations:

```
res <- outer(objs, objs, function(x, y) vector("list", length(x)))
combs <- combn(seq(objs), 2)
res[t(combs)] <- Vectorize(all.equal)(objs[combs[1,]], objs[combs[2,]])
res
```

Produces

```
    foo  bar         faz        
foo NULL Character,2 Character,2
bar NULL NULL        TRUE       
faz NULL NULL        NULL
```

This still shows the full matrix, but makes it obvious what comparisons produced what.

Comment: Good idea - being able to detect differences among non-first items would be handy. What about generating a matrix of name pairs to avoid the self-comparisons in `outer()`? `names <- c("foo", "bar", "faz"); pairs <- t(combn(names, 2)); apply(pairs, 1, function(x) all.equal(get(x[1]), get(x[2])))`

Comment: @treysp, agreed, see my modification.